# Does anyone know a better alternative to Google Translate API?

Tags: api, rest, google-translate

I already did similar search terms for this topic in this forum.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api

But that post is a bit old..  Things may have changed for about a year.  And I wonder does anybody know if there's any better REST-based API service that I can use out there since that post was last posted.

Thanks.

Comment: depends on your definition of **better**

Comment: Better as in superior quality to Google Translate with great technical API documentation. And probably it's not a paid service, if I can get away with it..

Comment: if you need quality, you have to pay. except Google.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Bing translator could be the substitute that u are looking for.

Comment: Haven't tried Bing Translator yet..  At the moment, I'm using MyMemory.net.  That's also free as well.

http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for alternatives as well and came across a npm package called [google-translate-api-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api-browser) which does work for my small project, but I can't assure big data translations or requests not being throttled